# Display date in mm/dd/yy format in a tab

Tags: excel, vba

I pull a date off a worksheet and paste it several places and use it to name a new tab.

```
Dim weD As Long

'Paste timesheet
Worksheets("calc").Range("B4").PasteSpecial

'Set week ending date variable for naming new worksheet later
weD = Worksheets("calc").Cells(14, "O").Value
```

This gives weD the value in the format of mm/dd/yy that it outputs on other sheets correctly.

But when I call the variable here:

```
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Week Ending " & weD
```

weD has the same value but in serial number format.

How do I make it so that the new tab has the correct format of mm/dd/yy?

Comment: Is ("Week Ending " & weD) exceeds 31 characters?, this may allow erros

Comment: Nope, EX." Week Ending 43632" which is 06/16/2019.

Comment: you can transform Column format with this line Worksheets("calc").Range("B4") = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")

Comment: Why can people not be bothered to [edit] the question when it's clearly referring to [tag:vba] **not** [tag:vbscript]?!

Comment: @dmitri-caragheaur next time before [approving an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/4450011) check the tags are relevant first, just adding code blocks isn't what I would call a substantial edit.

Comment: @Lankymart thanks for the advice, will do... just added code blocks to make the question look a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Try Modifying your code like so:

```
Worksheets("calc").Range("B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
             Operation:= xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Otherwise you can try:

```
With Worksheets("calc").Range("B4")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End With
```